# GitLab: How to reuse the applications installed in before_script stage into the next stages (Eg, test) without reinstalling

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have a testing project in **GitLab** which uses `Python`, `Robot Framework`, `Chrome` and `Selenium`. I am using the following `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: python:3.9

variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip
    - venv/

stages:
  - test_API1
  - test_API2

before_script:
  - python -V  # Print out python version for debugging
  - wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
  - echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
  - apt update -y
  - apt install -y google-chrome-stable
  - pip install virtualenv
  - virtualenv venv
  - source venv/bin/activate
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

API1:
  stage: test_API1
  when: manual
  script:
    - python3 -m robot.run -d Results1 Test/test_API1.robot  

API2:
  stage: test_API2
  script:
    - python3 -m robot.run -d Results2 Test/test_API2.robot
```

I specifically want the two Test Stages to be separate and in doing so, i have to go through the `before_script` stage two times, which slows down the overall pipeline.

Is there a better and faster way to have `Python`, `Robot Framework`, `Chrome` and `Selenium` installed in one stage and then reused in test stages? Can someone suggest any `docker images` which are already present to work for this scenario?

Comment: _Can someone suggest any docker images which are already present to work for this scenario?_ > Have you considered creating your own image with a [multi stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) and publish it on docker hub?